# In Scala using variables in a map reduces the performance?

Tags: performance, scala, garbage-collection

maybe it is a stupid question, but I have this doubt and I cannot find a response...
If I have a map operation on a list of complex objects and to make the code more readable I use intermediate variables inside the map the performance can change?

For example this are two versions of the same code:

```
 profilesGroupedWithIds map {
  c =>
    val blockId = c._2
    val entityIds = c._1._2
    val entropy = c._1._1
    if (separatorID < 0) BlockDirty(blockId, entityIds.swap, entropy)
    else BlockClean(blockId, entityIds, entropy)
}
```

..

```
profilesGroupedWithIds map {
  c =>
    if (separatorID < 0) BlockDirty(c._2, c._1._2.swap, c._1._1)
    else BlockClean(c._2, c._1._2, c._1._1)
}
```

As you can see the first version is more readable than the second one.

But the efficiency is the same? Or the three variables that I have created inside the map have to be removed by the garbage collector and this will reduce the perfomance (suppose that 'profilesGroupedWithIds' is a very big list)?

Thanks

Regards

Luca

Comment: [Which horse is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Considering how advanced are some optimizations performed by JVM, things like cache-friendliness, data locality and so on, there is virtually nothing that one can say without running benchmarks for a specific use case. But would assume, that the difference would be so insignifficant, that I would simply choose the more readable version and then start profiling once some actual perfrmance issue arises.

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- [Donald Knuth](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vals are just aliases for the tuple elements. So the generated java bytecode will be *identical* in both cases, and so will be the performance.

More importantly, the first variant is *much* better code since it clearly conveys the intent.

Here is a third variant that avoids accessing the tuple elements _1 and _2 entirely:

```
profilesGroupedWithIds map {
  case ((entropy,entityIds),blockId) =>
    if (separatorID < 0) BlockDirty(blockId, entityIds.swap, entropy)
    else BlockClean(blockId, entityIds, entropy)
}
```